# Copy a file from one directory and replace the file in multiple directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy a jar file from directory(source) and replace the file in the destination. But the problem is my destination directories are different as explained below:

Source=D:\temp\R56A

Target=D:\path\AP\Different_folders\lib\i2

### Target folder example:-

D:\path\AP\ABC1\lib\i2

D:\path\AP\XY_C\lib\i2

D:\path\AP\GHS3\lib\i2

I AM NOT ABLE TO FETCH THROUGH DIFFERENT FOLDER NAMES and the script not taking it.

This is for a windows box. Can we copy the folder name in a text file and call that text file as variable in a for loop? Is it possible?

```
@ECHO OFF
REM SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set Source=D:\temp\R56A
set Target=D:\path\AP\<Different_Directory_names>\lib\i2
set file=i2-bam.jar
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%Source%\%file%"') do (
    copy /V "%%f" "%Target%\" 2>nul
)
```

PART 2

```
@ECHO OFF
for /d "D:\temp\R56A\" %%f in (i2-bam.jar) do copy %%f "D:\path\AP\<Different_Directory_names>\lib\i2"
```

Comment: if the ***source*** file is unambiguous why do you do a `dir /s` ? Shouldn't you do this on the Target?

Comment: `for` does not accept a root path parameter; perhaps you meant `for /D /R`? Anyway, your code does not seem to fit your description; please [edit] your question and clarify...

Comment: I have made changes to the question. Hope it much more clear for you to help me with. I am struggling at the <Different folder names> in the destination directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Source=D:\temp\R56A"
Set "File=i2-bam.jar"
Set "Target=D:\path\AP"
Set "Sub=lib\i2"

If Not Exist "%Source%\%File%" Exit /B
If Not Exist "%Target%\" Exit /B

For /D %%A In ("%Target%\*")Do If Exist "%%A\%Sub%\" Copy /Y "%Source%\%File%" "%%A\%Sub%">Nul
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks. Meanwhile i also found another way (bit longer than the one you have provided) by placing the different folder names in a text file and calling the content of the text file through a variable in a for loop.